# How to test serverless lambda functions with constructors and dependencies?

Tags: node.js, tdd, aws-lambda, sinon, serverless-framework

How do I stub out a constructor to pass an expectation on the constructed object that it has received a function call?

I am using serverless, and I have a lambda function which has dependencies and runs every minute via a scheduled event. I want to focus on the behavior of the lambda function so I want one of my tests to be as follows -> it dequeues messages from message-queue. The test will verify that my queue has received a function, dequeueMessages - and that's it. Here's my sample lambda:

```
module.exports = function(event, context, callback) {
  var queue = new Queue();

  queue.dequeueMessages(params).then(messages => {
    var client = new DataFetcher();

    return client.fetchData(messages).then(data => {
      var database = new Database();

      return database.persist(data);
    })
  }
}
```

I know there are other dependencies there, but I just want to focus on getting the first test to pass, and I am struggling with stubbing out `new Queue` to make the assertion that the constructed object, queue, has invoked #dequeueMessages. I've explored [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/) and I have tests set up with mocha and chai, but I just don't know how to put all the tools together to do this very simple test.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to only focus on the implementation details, it's pretty straightforward.  I'm attaching a working example based on your sample files, with a couple of adjustments just for completeness.

### lib.js

This is module that mimics 3rd party dependencies - normally in your code that should be something like an AWS lib, etc.

```
class Queue{
  constructor(){

  }

  dequeueMessages(params ){
    console.log('dequeueMessages()', params);

    const messages = [];
    return Promise.resolve(messages);
  }

}

class DataFetcher{
  constructor(){

  }

  fetchData(messages ){
    console.log('fetchData()', messages);
    const data = {};
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }
}

class Database{
  constructor(){

  }

  persist(data ){
    console.log('persist()', data);

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}

module.exports.Queue = Queue;
module.exports.Database = Database;
module.exports.DataFetcher = DataFetcher;
```

### lambda.js

Altered it a bit so that it notifies its caller upon completion.

```
'use strict';

const Queue = require('./lib').Queue;
const DataFetcher = require('./lib').DataFetcher;
const Database = require('./lib').Database;


module.exports = function(event, context, callback) {
  var queue = new Queue();

  var params = {};

  queue.dequeueMessages(params).then(messages => {
    var client = new DataFetcher();

    return client.fetchData(messages).then(data => {
      var database = new Database();

      database.persist(data).then(() => {
        callback(null, {});
      });
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    callback(error);
  });
};
```

### test.js

```
'use strict';

const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

var sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');
sinonStubPromise(sinon);

chai.use(SinonChai);
chai.should();

const lambda = require('./lambda');
const Queue = require('./lib').Queue;
const DataFetcher = require('./lib').DataFetcher;
const Database = require('./lib').Database;

context('Test', () => {


  beforeEach(() => {
    if (!this.sandbox) {
      this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    } else {
      this.sandbox.restore();
    }
  });


  it('should pass the test',
    (done) => {

      const event = {};
      const ctx = {};

      const stubQueue = sinon.stub(Queue.prototype, 'dequeueMessages')
        .resolves(['1', '2']);
      const stubDataFetcher = sinon.stub(DataFetcher.prototype, 'fetchData')
        .resolves({});
      const stubDatabase = sinon.stub(Database.prototype, 'persist')
        .resolves();

      lambda(event, ctx, (error, result) => {

        try {
          // all stubs should have been called
          // one time each
          stubQueue.should.have.been.calledOnce;
          stubDataFetcher.should.have.been.calledOnce;
          stubDatabase.should.have.been.calledOnce;

          done();
        } catch (e) {
          done(e);
        }

      });
    });

});
```

The simplest thing you can do is to just stub the required methods at their prototype level and control their behavior accordingly.  In this example, we have stubbed the 3 methods of interest being used inside the lambda, so that they return a fabricated result in order to drive the test down the required path.

Finally, since the nature of the lambda is **async** we enforce it to make use of the callback so that we can gracefully run our assertions upon completion.

Using this as a skeleton, you can leverage all features that Sinon has to offer in order to validate thoroughly your implementation logic.

Last but not least, the article that @johni shared should really be used as a reference for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Great answer. No need for the external dependency lambda-tester.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend this [article](https://blog.atomdata.io/serverless-applications-continuous-delivery-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-part-1-unit-tests-e517aa1cd09e) which covers very important aspects when unit testing an AWS lambda function.

I have adopted the way they are doing it.